# jQuery: custom horizontal accordion width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Im trying to create a custom horizontal accordion style showcase. In terms of actual functionality, i have the framework (which can be seen here):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/adrianjacob/UdUus/

However my main bug bear (and the clients) is that if you look at the right hand side, there is always slight movement/flickering as the widths animate up and down.

Ideally I want it to appear smooth so only the opening/closing lists have movement.

ANy advice would be much appreciated.

A.

Comment: Hmmm... that's a tricky one. Must be to do with rounding error. I've been having a play with changing the widths to %ages, but it's no good. I'll keep at it and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Also been trying absolute positioning, but still can't get it to work. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function's `step` (it's not well documented)... I've updated the [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UdUus/117/)

```
var panels = $('#promo li');

panels.hoverIntent(

function() {
    if (!$(this).is('.expanded') && !panels.is(':animated')) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: 200
        }, {
            // width is the calculated width, ani is the animation object
            step: function(width, ani) {
                var w = Math.floor(width);
                // use 250 so we end up with 50 as the reduced size
                $('.expanded').css('width', (250 - w) + 'px');
                $(ani.elem).css('width', (200 - w) + 'px');
            },
            duration: 500,
            complete: function() {
                panels.removeClass('expanded');
                $(this).addClass('expanded');
            }
        });
    }
}, function() {});
```

A similar method is used in the [Kwicks](http://mottie.github.com/Kwicks/) plugin.

Comment: +1 Still jitters a little in Chrome, but almost imperceptibly!

Comment: Fudgey...Is there a way too edit (http://www.jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UdUus/117/) so all panels start off at equal width and then smoothly expand/contract?

Comment: It's a little more complicated to do that because you'll have to calculate and save evenly expanded and contracted panel sizes. What you are asking for now is exactly what the Kwicks plugin does, so might I suggest you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this plugin](http://www.portalzine.de/index?/Horizontal_Accordion) which may have figured out the bug. The example provided was too showy to actually tell.

Have you played around with jQuery UI easings?

Comment: That plugin doesn't do very well if you resize the screen :( too bad it looks nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to stop the event just when the div is opening.

The website with explanation is: http://api.jquery.com/stop/